# What is the missing number in set B?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

A {6, 2, 2, 2, 16, 2} 
B {37, 37, 3, 3, 3, ?}

The numbers in set A relate to one another through a numerical or abstract pattern.  Set B has a similar or a somewhat contrasting pattern  .The task in this short but hard puzzle is to identify the logic and complete the incomplete set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be far too simple but:

> 3?

Reasoning:

> 6 least prime factor is 2
>  2 least prime factor is 2
>  etc...
>  Since list B is all prime, only prime numbers are returned